# \autocite help with multiple entries in a single footnote

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using BibTex and trying to get more than one citation in each footnoted citation.  For example, this is what I want:

> 1. D. C. Greetham, ``Introduction,’’ Scholarly Editing: a Guide to Research. New York: The Modern Language Association, 1995. pp. 1-7. p. 2. **As cited in** Kelemen, Erick. Textual Editing and Criticism: An Introduction. USA: W. W. Norton & Co., 2009. p. 5.

But right now all I have is

```
\autocite[As cited in][5]{Kelemen2009}
```

I cannot figure out how to include the first citation with the second.  I was thinking of maybe \cite in the note section but I could not really find a good layout that fits with the Chicago referencing style.

Note:This is in the case of not having a cross-referenced entry.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

*bolded "as cited in" not necessary, just there to try and make the division easier to see.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following should work:

```
\autocites[2]{Greetham1995}[as cited in][5]{Kelemen2009}
```

With the `\…cites` commands (note the plural form) you can cite multiple works with one command. You can add prenotes and postnotes to every single work cited as well as to the whole command. See the biblatex documentation for details.